# I am getting the error 'Response' object has no attribute 'fromstring'

Tags: python, django, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to use xpath in my django app and I keep getting the error

```
'Response' object has no attribute 'fromstring'
```

I don't understand why. I have researched and the only thing I saw was people having probblems with text instead of from string. Heres my code

```
def panties():
    from lxml import html
    pan_url = 'http://www.panvideos.com'
    html = requests.get(pan_url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
    video_row = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'video'})

    def youtube_link(url):
        youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        tree = html.fromstring(youtube_page.content)

        the_link = tree.xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/h1')

        return the_link

    entries = [{'text': div.h4.text,
                'href': div.a.get('href'),
                'tube': youtube_link(div.a.get('href')),
                } for div in video_row][:1]

    return entries
```

any help would be great.

Edit: 
I'm following the hitchhikers guide to python but while I search for answers I' keep seeing people use etree and not the way he's using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't nest functions like this. Un-nest your function and it will work fine.

You define `html = requests.get(*)`

What this returns is a response object.

In your nested function you're using this `html` instead of what you imported `from lxml import html` because of the namespace(s).

Comment: that's what it was. I'm really new to python. Thanks

Comment: is it possible to scrape the youtube icon that shows in media players to get the link. I have been trying for weeks now to no avail.

Comment: yes and other sites that use youtube. It's not working for me at all. I went from beautifulsoup4 to xpath seeing If I could grab it and no luck

Comment: I tried this 'the_link = tree.xpath('//*[@tabindex="-1"]/a/@href')' and still nothing